# Blue prism- How can i get number of rows in a dynamic html table

Tags: automation, ui-automation, blueprism

I am using concept of dynamic path to element to grab contents inside the dynamic table. but still i want to find out a way to get the upper bounds for the captured table. Say, the number of rows and columns of the table element.

Path for the dynamic table:

```
/HTML/BODY(1)/DIV(15)/TABLE(1)/TBODY(1)/TR/TD
```

Path for the table content

```
/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[14]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR/TD**[3]**/DIV[1]/DIV**[1]**/DIV/DIV
```

Bold highlighted values needs to be incremented in order to point each cell data. I just want to know how many TD and DIV available to make the judgement on this.

```
/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[14]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR/TD  
/HTML/BODY[1]/DIV[14]/TABLE[1]/TBODY[1]/TR/TD**[3]**/DIV[1]/DIV
```

Comment: Did you try "MS Excel VBO", in it there is an object "Get numer of rows" if I remember correctly.

Comment: Hi @RAFEL, It's noting to do with Ms Excel VBO. what I am trying to explain is html dynamic web tables

Comment: Sry, i was reading your post early in the morning, too early apparently. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To read the table to the collection**

1. Spy the Table in Application Modeler.
2. Place box "Read" - use element table from previous step, Set Data as "Get Table", choose where to store the data.

As you see, the Blue Prism is pretty well designed in regards of interacting with the hmtl tables.

**To read amount of rows**

1. Read the table to collection
2. Use Action "Count Rows" from standard Blue Prism "Collections" object.

**To read amount of columns**

1. Read the table to collection
2. Use Action "Count Columns" from standard Blue Prism "Collections" object.